# How to click on a button and append button caption to new line in a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have created a form and would like to click on a button named "john" to add a new line to an existing table called "log", containing the date+time of clicking on the button and the name "john".

I have two tables "log" and "Team". "log" needs to be populated instead "Team" has a list of names and associated number

I started with a query called "append"

```
INSERT INTO log ( [time], name, no )
SELECT Now() AS [time], Team.namesurname AS name, Team.no AS no
FROM Team;
```

then I tried moving over to VBA because I would like use the name of the button "john" to filter the "append" query

```
Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String

stDocName = "append"
stLinkCriteria = Me!button.Caption

DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, , acNew
stLinkCriteria = Team![namesurname]
```

Of course nothing works :( or rather, if I execute the query manually it appends all names in "Team" with the correct timestamp instead of just "john".

I have read quite a lot of helps but I am getting more and more confused. I've also thought of trying to somehow create the sql from the "append" query in vbscript, but don't know where to start and would regardless not know how to use the button name to filter.

As a final result I am trying to create a form with approx 10 buttons all adding lines to the "log" table.

Could someone give me a shove in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0):

First, your query could look:

```
INSERT INTO log ( [time], [name], [no] )
SELECT Now() AS [time], Team.namesurname AS [name], Team.no AS [no]
FROM Team;
```

though is probably isn't very useful as it will insert a bunch of records.

Second, an action query is not opened but *executed* and you don't need a saved query - it is faster to write it directly:

```
Dim NameJohn As String
Dim ThisNo As Long
Dim SQL As string

NameJohn = Me!button.Caption
ThisNo = 8 ' any number.

SQL = "INSERT INTO log ( [time], [name], [no] ) VALUES ( Now(), '" & NameJohn & "', " & CStr(ThisNo) & " )"

CurrentDb.Execute SQL
```